# Test click.prompt in an interactive session

Tags: python, pytest, python-click

I wonder how I can test consecutive `click.prompt`.

Questions regarding testing input prompts of python click seem to focus [on one prompt only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50592219/testing-click-application-prompting-with-multiple-inputs). One [example](https://gist.github.com/lbillingham/6412cdc19f9a44901b03841e0443fbf7) focusses on one prompt given via command line.

Here [github mwe](https://github.com/Boltzmann/ClickPrompt) I try to test consecutive prompts.

```python
import click

@click.group()
@click.option('--option/--no-option', default=False)
def cli(option):
    click.echo(click.prompt('Type something'))
    # Todo later: click.echo(click.prompt('Type something else'))
    click.echo('Option is %s' % ('on' if option else 'off'))

@cli.command()
def function():
    click.echo('Functioning')
```

Something like

```python
import click
from click.testing import CliRunner

import cli

def test_sync():
    runner = CliRunner()
    result = runner.invoke(cli.cli, ['--debug', 'sync'], input='test')
    assert result.exit_code == 0
    assert 'Option is on' in result.output
    assert 'test' in result.output
```

however fails:

```
$ python -m pytest test_clickprompt.py   

    def test_sync():
        runner = CliRunner()
        result = runner.invoke(cli.cli, ['--debug', 'sync'], input='test\\n')
>       assert result.exit_code == 0
E       assert 2 == 0
E        +  where 2 = <Result SystemExit(2)>.exit_code

test_clickprompt.py:9: AssertionError
======================================================= short test summary info =======================================================
FAILED test_clickprompt.py::test_sync - assert 2 == 0
```

Comment: The shown error is just a syntax error because you try to use a key (`input`) in a list, which won't work.

Comment: OK, I changed the code to show another try. I also made the example easier to get a test for only one click.prompt input. Sry for the other asserts that now could be true, if the first assert would be OK.

Comment: OK, the test part of the mwe was not written good. Will post the solution here, @MrBeanBremen gave the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [MRBean Bremen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12480730/mrbean-bremen) pointed out, the input statement must be outside the list. After that the last two asserts needed to change for a green test.

```
import click
from click.testing import CliRunner

import cli

def test_sync():
    runner = CliRunner()
    result = runner.invoke(cli.cli, ['--option', 'function'], input='test\ntest')
    assert result.exit_code == 0
    assert "test\ntest" in result.output
    assert "debug" not in result.output
```